# How to trigger a jquery event if a given value is selected from a calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the ui date picker widget here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

to populate this:

```
<input id="date" value="" type="textbox" />
```

I would like to trigger a jquery event after a date is selected, but am unsure of how to call this, i know that i can do things like keyup, click, etc. but is there a way to do this if a value is selected from the widget?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$('#date').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, uiInstance) {
        // Do stuff with it
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly [from the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) (under the events tab):

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       // Put your code here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

datepicker has a callback function you can use initiate some functionality after a date is selected.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
});
```